# How can I have a searchable Qlistview in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a `QListView` which displays a list of items using PyQt in **Python**. How can I get it to return a qlistview specific item when searched for?

For example, if I have the following `Qlistview` with 4 items, how can I get the item which contains text = dan? or bring it to the top of the list. Also, the search doesn't need to be completely specific, If I type "da" I'd like it to return dan or items that starts with "da" and possibly bring it to the top of the list

[image: QListWidget]

My Qlistview is defined as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os
import sys

class AppView(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.ShowItemsList()

    def ShowItemsList(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("List")
        buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(self)
        buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        listview = QtGui.QListView(self)

        verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(listview)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.close)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(listview)
        with open("names-list.txt") as input:
            if input is not None:
                item = input.readlines()
            for line in item:
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(line)
                item.setCheckable(True)
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.PartiallyChecked)
                model.appendRow(item)

        listview.setModel(model)
        listview.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = AppView()
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it like this. I made my model an instance variable beginning with self so that I can access it from another function.

```
def searchItem(self):
    search_string = self.searchEditText.text() # Created a QlineEdit to input search strings
    items = self.model.findItems(search_string, QtCore.Qt.MatchStartsWith)
    if len(items) > 0:
        for item in items:
            if search_string:
                self.model.takeRow(item.row()) #take row of item
                self.model.insertRow(0, item)  # and bring it to the top
    else:
        print "not found"
```